# Pass model into template from Surface Controller

Tags: c#, content-management-system, umbraco

Is there a way I can pass in a populated object or list into a template / view from a surface controller in Umbraco 7?

Comment: Can you give us a bit more to go on?  Code examples?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a good spot to use ViewData.  There isn't much info in the question so I am kind of winging it here, but something like this...

// your surface controller

```
public ActionResult SubmitForm(YourFormModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        var submitResults = ResultsOfYourCode();
        ViewData["submitResults"] = submitResults;
        return RedirectToCurrentUmbracoPage();
    }
}
```

// your view

```
@{
    var submitResults = (submitResultsType)@ViewData["submitResults"];
}
<p>@submitResults.Property1</p>
```

This is totally untested and is just off the top of my head to give you an idea.